# Layout Preview showing blank screen with Coordinator layout in Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

This is layout design code when I open the layout preview page grey android screen shows only (android...CoordinatorLayout) and nothing is showing on the screen. How can I solve this problem, I want to show the layout design on Layout Preview Screen.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".activity.AddDietActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        android:background="@drawable/menubar">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/submitBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:onClick="clickToAddDiet"
            android:text="Save"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#fff"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_add_diet" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 19):

I was getting the same issue and after clicking on the info icon in the layout editor, I found out why:

[image]

Change the Theme in Editor to `AppCompat` or another theme that inherits it. Worked for me.

Comment: Never clicked on the info icon before. It's like a whole new world.

Answer (score 1):

I was targeting android sdk 28 and used `implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.+'` and it was then, that i faced this same problem.
And then i tried all the solutions found on many posts but none of them worked, I even added style items manually but it was tiresome, so I switched down to `implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.+'` and then it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this happened after updating the versions on some of my dependencies.  The only thing I had to do was recompile my project.  From the file menu in Android Studio, Build >> Make Project... or Ctrl+F9.  After this, the preview was back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

You did not close your `CoordinatorLayout` with `</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>`. Also, you would want to use a `ConstraintLayout` to make your included layout appears below your `AppBarLayout`.

Comment: I think he post the demo of Layout

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your App's build.gradle file, you have the proper implementation declaration. It has changed from the old statement of "compile" to:

**prior to Android Studio 3**

```
 compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

**in Android Studio 3**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change app theme to “App compat:dialog” in design view.This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the content of the Styles.xml 
 - `"Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"` to `"Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"`
    and re-built the app.

if this does not work try to change the theme

[Change the theme image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atjPV.png)
Change the theme to light version.
[Light theme selection image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiaEQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just update your android studio to 3.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Update to Android Studio 3.2.1 from 3.1.1 fix all the problems related to Coordinate Layout  preview page grey android screen showing only (android...CoordinatorLayout) and nothing showing on the screen

Android 3.2.1  [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/)

Answer (score 0):

The info window that @MateusGondim mentioned in his answer also suggests that you clean and rebuild the project. I did so, the error went away, and the layout preview started working again.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my problem about **Android Preview screen shows android…coordinatorlayout**

1.Check dependencies within your application gradle build file for possible  duplicate implementation of "`com.android.support:design:28.0.0"` (it should not be duplicated).

2.Go to your *res folder* -> *values* -> *styles* and change your app theme
`"Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"` to `"Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"`

3. *File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart* -
   it worked for me hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Things You Can Do

1. Refresh the layout
2. Sync Project
3. Clean Project
4. Rebuild Project
5. ADD Dependency implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
6. Build Project (Recommended, most of the Layout issues will be Solved
   by Doing This )
7. Refractor -> Migrate to Androidx.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30123244)